# Session.add() does not add anything but also doesn't fail

Tags: sqlalchemy, python-3.4

I am trying to insert data into a database using the following code:

```
print("New Account: {}".format(new_acc))
session.add(new_acc)
if pers_inf is not None:
    session.add(pers_inf)
print(session.dirty)
session.commit()
print("Number of Accounts after adding: {}".format(session.query(dbquery).filter_by(**param).count()))
session.close()
```

new_acc is not empty and session.add() does not throw any exception but session.dirty returns an empty IdentitySet and nothing is inserted into the database. Can anyone give me a hint on how to continue debugging here?

Comment: The identity set of `Session.new` is where you’ll find new instances, not `Session.dirty`.

Comment: Thank you. I have solved the issue by changing to a newer Python version, I was using a very old Ubuntu 14.04 VM.